# Click handlers for edit and save buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code from a JavaScript file:

```
$("body").on("click",".edit",function(){
    var list=$(this).closest("a").data("list");
    var seira=$(this).closest("a").data("order");
    //alert(navbar_edit[list][seira]);
    var edit=navbar_edit[list][seira];
    navbar_edit[list][seira]=prompt("Change property",edit);
    exportLists();

});
$("body").on("click",".edit-save",function(){
    var property=$(this).closest("a").text();
    property=property.substring(0,property.length-4);
    alert(property);
    var list=$(this).closest(".list-group").attr("id");
    list=list.substring(list.length-1);
    navbar_edit[list].push(property);
    exportLists();
});
```

As you can see, I use `$("body")` 3 times to execute 3 different actions. Is there any way to use it only once so I can reduce my code?

Comment: I only see two `$("body")` and two click handlers.

Comment: It's rather difficult to review just these two handlers in isolation without context. It would help if you also showed us a sample of the HTML and explained the goal that you are trying to achieve. Also, what does `exportLists()` do, and is it related to all this jQuery selection stuff?

Comment: almost the whole html content is generated via jquery

Comment: Can you just describe it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many jQuery methods, [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) returns jQuery object which you can use for chaining purpose.

Sidenote: You should take into account that [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) method may return `null` if the user cancel dialog. Therefore you have to check the returning value before assigning it to the target variable (`navbar_edit[list][seira]`).

So the code may look like this:

```
$("body").on("click",".edit",function(){
    var list=$(this).closest("a").data("list");
    var seira=$(this).closest("a").data("order");
    //alert(navbar_edit[list][seira]);
    var edit=navbar_edit[list][seira];
    var v=prompt("Change property",edit);
    if (v) navbar_edit[list][seira]=v;
    exportLists();

}).on("click",".edit-save",function(){
    var property=$(this).closest("a").text();
    property=property.substring(0,property.length-4);
    alert(property);
    var list=$(this).closest(".list-group").attr("id");
    list=list.substring(list.length-1);
    navbar_edit[list].push(property);
    exportLists();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**A few notes:**

Always use `.slice` over `.substring` (Yes `.slice` works on strings.), it will support negative selection af strings, eg `"abc".slice(0, -1) // "ab"`
Storing reused values / objects in variables cleans up the code a lot, eg:

```
var a = $(this).find('.element').attr('a');
var b = $(this).find('.element').attr('b');
// The above can be written as: 
var $element = $(this).find('.element');
var a = $element.attr('a');
var b = $element.attr('b');
// This is faster and is IMO easier to read.
```

Meaningful variable names, dont use names like `seira` when you are referring to an index in an array call it `index` or `list_index` etc. (I assume its meaningful in another language but IMO all code should be written in english with english comments, and english variable names.)

**Code:**

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var $a = $(this).closest('a');
    var list_id = $a.data('list');
    var index = $a.data('order');

    var current_value = navbar_edit[list][index];
    var new_value = prompt('Change Property', current_value);

    navbar_edit[list][index] = new_value;

    exportLists();
});
$(document.body).on('click', '.edit-save', function() {
    var $a = $(this).closest('a');
    var $listGroup = $(this).closest('.list-group');

    var value = $a.text().slice(0, -4);
    var list_id = $listGroup.attr('id').slice(0, -1); // remove last char

    navbar_edit[list_id].push(value);

    exportLists();
});
```

Comment: well seira in greek is simillar to index.Thanks anyway

Comment: All-English code makes more sense. However, if you are going to use Greek, why not write `σειρά`? That's a valid JavaScript identifier.

Comment: I didn't know I could use Greek characters